# Bluescreen 0x0000003B during DownloadFileAsync?

Tags: c#, http, .net-4.0, download, bsod

I've run into a problem with an application I'm developing in C#/.NET. A problem I can't trace down because it causes my system to crash with a BSOD. Here's the minidump:

060310-27066-01.dmp 03.06.2010 19:47:39 SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION 0x0000003b 00000000`c0000005 fffff800`0306d4d0 fffff880`0b107640 00000000`00000000 ntoskrnl.exe ntoskrnl.exe+70600 NT Kernel & System Microsoft® Windows® Operating System Microsoft Corporation 6.1.7600.16539 (win7_gdr.100226-1909) x64  C:\Windows\Minidump\060310-27066-01.dmp 4 15 7600

It's not related specifically to DownloadFileAsync. Other methods of the System.Net assembly classes related to HTTP download also make my system crash. I really hope someone can help me with this.

Just for info: other apps (browsers etc.) that download files work like a charm.

If you need further information don't hesitate to ask!

Thanks!

**// Update 06.06.2010 - 02:58:** Just for info: I ran memtest86+ to check my memory modules a few days ago. There were some errors when all four 2GB modules were installed. I removed 3 of them and checked all 4 modules again one by one without any errors. The BSOD occurs solely when my app is run in the debugger and downloads something from the web.

**// Update 04.06.2010 - 18'53:** I figured out after testing several things that the BSOD occurs whenever I run my own application inside the Visual Studio 2010 debugger and start a download. Running the app with no debugger attached to it isn't causing the BSOD.

I suppose that the BSOD is somehow related to the debugger.

Comment: Do you experience any problems with other applications causing BSODs? This problem can be related to so many things, faulty memory chips, bad driver (network?), unless you can find someone that can help you look at the mini-dump which might provide some insight to the cause, it will probably be a trial and error process to determine the root cause.

Comment: The minidump is actually at C:\Windows\Minidump\060310-27066-01.dmp on your machine. Download [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx), run `WinDbg`, load the minidump file, and run `!analyze -v`. Or post your file somewhere and I'll take a quick look.

Comment: I've uploaded it to my server. Here's the URL: http://www.seveq.de/crash_1.dmp I'd really be grateful if you could have a look at it.

@Chris Taylor: no, not that I know of. Downloading stuff with other applications works like a charm.

Comment: I have downloaded debugging tools and debugging symbols. Now I'm trying to get any information out of the dump file. But I can't see anything there because it seems I don't have any debugging symbols for ntoskrnl.exe. Are there any?

Comment: So... I ran a memtest last night. There were some errors. I tried to figure out which memory module had caused these errors by removing 3 of the 4 modules and testing every single module on its own with the memory test that reported the errors. But guess what! None of the modules was reported faulty. And the BSOD still occurs. It is repeatable. I can trigger it by running my download app. After a few seconds of downloading my system crashes with the BSOD. I'm at a loss...

Comment: @SteveQ, did you run the chkdsk? It might point to a corrupt location on the disk which is being loaded by VS (while debugging?) and resulting in the BSOD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, just to close this question... Now, two years after I had asked this question, I'm not experiencing this anymore. The problem has dissolved, apparently, because I've reinstalled my operating system several times in the meantime. Unfortunately, I've never figured out why this BSOD occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Update your network card drivers.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably something wrong with your network drivers. Try reinstalling the network drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if there are any updates available for your mobo BIOS and chipset.  Debugging exercises much of the same task-switching logic as the core OS thread scheduler to save the state of the process / state of the CPU, but the timing is very different from the thread scheduler.

Check the manufacturer's web site, don't rely solely on Windows Update.

It wouldn't hurt to see if there are updates for your graphics card and other hardware, too.

Comment: I have already updated my BIOS to the newest revision. I'll take a look if updates of chipset drivers etc. are available, install them and keep you informed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuantely no specific cause can be gleened from the mini dump, at least there is not much I could see (possibly others would know better).

If you look in your windows folder you should find a memory.dmp file. That will be larger, but hopefully contain some piece of information that can be used to idntify the possible source of the problem.

Some things you can try in the meantime

1. Run a tool like [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) to check the system memory for any possible problems.
2. Check the windows eventlog for any error messages relating to the harddisk, maybe you are seeing the first signs of HDD loss and the problem is presenting here. You can also run a [chkdsk](http://www.w7forums.com/use-chkdsk-check-disk-t448.html).

Comment: Thanks for looking at the mini dump!

I checked my memory last night with some weird results. First there were some errors that I could reproduce while all 4 modules (4x 2GB) were installed. Next I checked every module on its own. But, as mentioned above, without any error. So I can't tell which of the modules might be broken. If any... 

Next I thought that might be caused by a hard disk defect. But it also occurs when I download a file to another location on a totally different drive.

Comment: Just because you don't get errors with 1 stick doesn't mean it's fine. This test can show false negatives, just never false positives. I'd scrap all the ram and get some new sticks because bsod's are NOT related to downloading files, your ram is broken.

Comment: Yea, in particular two modules on one channel is more stressful to the memory controller than one module per channel. Try lowering the speed the memory runs at.

Answer (score 0):

Open an admin console, then execute 'sfc /scannow'. This will possibly fix any corrupted files in your Windows install.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310747 for more details.

Comment: Thanks. It ran through without any results. There are no corrupted system files.

Comment: It normally doesn't give results afaik :) Is the problem still there? I remember that I had a problem with downloads once, mainly that they would completely freeze up firefox occasionally and make it non-closable. sfc sorted that out :)

Comment: Okay, in that case I have to double check if the problem persists... just a moment. Might take some minutes to boot my PC in case of another BSOD. Well, at least I don't have to shut it down before rebooting. ;-) I'll be back in a minute or two...

Comment: Yepp... just as I expected. BSOD problem persists.